# portlet:renderURL not working

Tags: liferay, portlet, liferay-6

I am working on liferay 6 Portlet development.
I am new to it.
I need to keep a Hyperlink to another jsp this way as shown.

```
<a href="<portlet:renderURL>
    <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/WEB-INF/view/page2.jsp" />
    </portlet:renderURL>">
</a>
```

I have another JSP called page2.jsp , but this isn't working (Means when i click on the hyper link , it aain displays the First JSP only

But this isn't working

**This is my page1.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>

<s:form action="helloForm" method="POST" theme="simple">
    Enter Your Name:<s:textfield name="namer" value="%{name}" required="true"/>
    <s:submit/>
</s:form>


<a href="<portlet:renderURL>
<portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/WEB-INF/view/page2.jsp" />
</portlet:renderURL>">
</a>
```

=========

**This is pag2.jsp**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hi </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post the `doView()` method of the portlet (or equivalent in the framework you're using)?

Comment: Just a little piece of advice: A portlet jsp should not contain the tags: `html`,`head` and `body`. Everything we write in portlet JSPs should be a fragment inside the `body` tag and these outer tags are taken care of by the portal itself. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try the following code in your page1.jsp and see if it works:

```
<portlet:renderURL var="clickRenderURL">
    <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/WEB-INF/view/page2.jsp" />
</portlet:renderURL>

<a href="<%=clickRenderURL %>">Click here</a>
```

If it does than may be this is the issue with quotes ("").

If it does not then can you provide more details like which portlet are you extending MVCPortlet, etc.

Comment: please don't use scritplet syntax in 2012, it's almost always better to use `${varname}` or `<c:out value="varname"/>`

Comment: @soulcheck: I was going to edit my answer to also include an EL version. By the way liferay uses scriptlets a lot if you have gone through their source code. Anyways Thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: I thought I'd mention it for rookie devvers who might start to use it seeing it all around the place in liferay, etc.  liferay does it and it's really ugly and unmaintainable. They have some jsp's where 99% of content is java (they could actually rename the file and it would almost compile ;)). That's just plain wrong since it breaks view-controller separation.

Comment: i always shiver when I have to modify liferay-included portlets :/

Comment: This is what liferay's philosophy is in using scriptlets, if anybody is interested: http://www.manning.com/sezov/LiA_SampleChapter-04.pdf. Can scroll down to section 4.2.2, 2nd para

Comment: hah, wonder what kind of designers was author working with, casue 99% of those I know are quite proficient in html and css (and not at all in java). Also, in my experience, tool support for java-in-jsp is is a bit worse than java-in-java. But to each his own.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem happens in the tag.

In MVCPortlet, if you want to call a JSP page directly from another JSP page, you have to name the the portlet:param's name as "mvcPath", say:

```
<portlet:renderURL var="varA">
    <portlet:param name="mvcPath" value="/a.jsp"/>
</portlet:renderURL>

<portlet:renderURL var="varB">
    <portlet:param name="mvcPath" value="/b.jsp"/>
</portlet:renderURL>

<a href="<%=varA %>">Link to A</a>
<a href="<%=varB %>">Link to B</a>
```

This will work fine.

Hope this will help you.